# How to remove duplicate values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below code appends text in a box  how to avoid entering duplicate values..?

```
 $('#plan td.n').click(function(){
 $(this).html('B').css("background-color","red");
 $("input:text").val(this.id);

 var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();  
 $(".list").append("<div class = 'item'>" + toAdd + "</div>")//add the seat number to box 



 });
```

Comment: Plus One for using a CodeCademy example! (or so I think)

Comment: Keep a lookup array/object which will hold the value of `toAdd` then before appending check if its already in the lookup

Comment: sorry bro i am can please show me

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do something like this below. Hope it helps

```
var lookupObj = {};
var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
if(!lookupObj[toAdd]) {
    $(".list").append("<div class = 'item'>" + toAdd + "</div>")
    lookupObj[toAdd] = true;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I totally drafted a completely different and overcomplicated version of this that was at least ten times as long. Then I saw the little gray box that said: 'A new answer to this question has been posted'. I clicked on it. This popped up. I deleted my answer without posting. :)

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code ? jsfiddle or codepen or any other way you choose to share with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your markup looks like this:

```
<input name="checkListItem" value=""/>
<input type="submit" class="addItem" value="Add/Remove"/>
<div class="list">

</div>
```

You can add an event which filters items which match the text (exactly) of the current `.val()` of the checkListItem input, which lets you delete the item in the list if it is a duplicate.

```
$('.addItem').on('click', function() {

  var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val(),
      exists = $('.item').filter(function() {
                 return $(this).text() == toAdd;
               });

  if (exists.length > 0) {
    exists.remove();
  } else {
    $(".list").append("<div class = 'item'>" + toAdd + "</div>");
  }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/milesrobinson/563h1fq6/

Comment: Why don't you share your HTML and JavaScript using jsfiddle.net? Can you confirm that the demo I linked to does what you hope your code will do?

Comment: bro i am responding very last. can limit this so i can ony see 4 values.

Comment: if (countclick <4){
 var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val().substring(1,4),
      exists = $('.item').filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() == toAdd;
   });
    }
  if (exists.length > 0 ) {

   exists.remove();
  } else {
   $(".list").append("<div class = 'item'>" + toAdd + "</div>");
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
// if you don't care the performance, this is the easy way
var finded = false;
$(".list > .item").each(function(idx){
    if (toAdd === $(this).html()) {
        finded = true;
        return false;
    }
});

if (!finded) {
     $(".list").append("<div class = 'item'>" + toAdd + "</div>")
}
```